# How to render a list of values using JDatabase 1.5 instead of mysql?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

I have made a **mysql query**, in to a **php** file and I want to do same thing but using **JDatabase**. Let's say for example, we have a **table** with two **columns**, column **name** and column **image**. Those two columns, contains **ten rows**. I want to make a **list** in my php code, that will render something like this:

```
Name | Image        |
---------------------
AAAA | blahblah.png |
---------------------
BBBB | hahahaha.png |
---------------------
```

I have made it work using mysql but for some reasons, I should make it using JDatabase. Take an example on what I have now:

This is my query:

```
$query="SELECT m.name, l.image
          FROM table1 AS m, table2 AS l
         WHERE m.id BETWEEN 70 AND 80
           AND l.id = 10
         ORDER BY m.id ASC";

$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
```

This is my php code:

```
<?php $count = 0; while ($count < $num){
      $image = mysql_result($result,$count,"image"); ?>
<div><img src="'.$image.'"/></div><?php $count++;}?>
```

How can I do the same thing using JDatabase and not mysql?

Comment: Why you closed this question? Why this question is off topic? Did I ask about cooking or something? Isn't it relative to programming? Some guys in here are very "funny"!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another example:

```
<?php
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();        
$query="SELECT m.name, l.image
          FROM table1 AS m, table2 AS l
         WHERE m.id BETWEEN 70 AND 80
           AND l.id = 10
         ORDER BY m.id ASC";
$db->setQuery( $query );
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach( $rows as $row ): ?>
    <div><img src="<?php echo $row->image ?>"/></div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

EDIT: 
To access these rows from outside of the loop you can do so by:

```
$image_1st = $rows[0];
$image_2nd = $rows[1];
$image_3rd = $rows[2];
```

...and so on

```
$image_1st_src = $image_1st->image;
$image_1st_src = $rows[0]->image;
```

Comment: One more question... What if I want to sent this result to unique variables??? I mean, let's say we have 9 rows and I want to do something like this:

`$image_1 = 1st_row->image;
$image_2 = 2nd_row->image;
$image_3 = 3rd_row->image;
$image_4 = 4th_row->image;
$image_5 = 5th_row->image;
$image_6 = 6th_row->image;
$image_7 = 7th_row->image;
$image_8 = 8th_row->image;
$image_9 = 9th_row->image;`

Comment: I love you man!!! Hahahahaha... Thank you very much!!! :)

Comment: I did up-vote some of your answers around stackoverflow to thank you!!! Shhhh...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this-

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();        
$query = "SELECT beta
            FROM table
           WHERE alpha BETWEEN 70 AND 80
           ORDER BY alpha ASC LIMIT 4 , 1";

$db->setQuery($query);
$beta = $db->loadResult();
```

Comment: And if I want query have no limits and get value after, using something like this ...`$beta = $db->loadResult($i)`? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @DNA180: you can use loadObjectList or loadAssocList for more than one result. OR Read here http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase/1.5

Comment: Well I found that. If I do something like this: 
`$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
$itemrow = $rows[0];
$username = $itemrow->username;`
gives me the value of column username only from first row. What is the syntax if I want in `$itemrow` all usernames of all rows? Thank you for your time!!!

Comment: @DNA180: You can try loadResultArray()

Comment: My friend I just edit the question and made it more detailed take a look if you have the kindness!!! Thank you!!!